# Create a dataframe of monthly correlations from daily returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assuming I have daily returns for 5 stocks in my dataframe `df`, over a period of two years:

I want to create a new DataFrame `df2` comprising of monthly pairwise **correlations** between my 5 stocks.
`df2` would look like this:

```
Month-year    AB_rho   AC_rho   AD_rho   AE_rho   BC_rho   BD_rho   BE_rho  CD_rho  CE_rho    DE_rho 
Jan2018
Feb2018
Mar2018
..
...
..
Oct2019
Nov2019
Dec2019
```

I am attempting to use the pd.Grouper(freq='M') function. I would like to replicate this for quarters as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the daily correlation calculated in each month, you can try some like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

def get_pairwise_corr(corr):
    mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr),1)
    mask = np.where(mask.reshape(-1))
    return corr.values.reshape(-1)[mask]

df2 = df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%b%Y')).apply(lambda x: get_pairwise_corr(x.corr()))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(df2.values),
                   columns=[c[0]+c[1]+'_rho' for c in combinations(df.columns,2)],
                   index=df2.index)
```